# APC on WampServer Windows 7 not working

Tags: php, windows-7, window, wampserver, apc

I'm trining to add APC on my WampServer in local,

I've try many version of php_apc.dll, i've put it in my php "ext"

I've try to add this line in php.ini

```
"extension=php_apc.dll"

[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1
```

My configuration :

```
Window 7
Wamp 2.4
Php v.5.4.12
Apache v.2.4.4
```

I've php_apc.dll and the extension in menu php extensions, but i can't active it (the server stay in orange status without any displayed any error)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and installed wampserver 2.2, with PHP 5.3.10 and worked for me.